# ACM Digital Library Search Problems

Tags: researchkit, safe-publication

I have problems using the ACM advanced search at https://dl.acm.org/search/advanced
I only want to search for abstracts, so I choose the abstract field in the "Search within" block.
To provide a simple example, I use the following search query:

**change impact AND software AND graph AND algorithm**

With that, I got 179 Results.

I double checked the results by looking in the first abstract (Multi-perspective change impact analysis using linked data of software engineering) and everything was fine. But in the second abstract (Change impact analysis for aspect-oriented software evolution) the terms for "graph" and "algorithm" are missing.

I did some testing with something like:

**change impact AND (software OR artifact) AND scenario**

and got results where the "scenario" term is missing in the abstract.
My original search term is way more complex than that simple example.

So what I am missing or is the search engine broken?

Comment: This is asking about use of another product.  Do we do Tech Support here?

Comment: Just as an example

Comment: I have the same problem. The query is correct but it includes results that simply do not match the query.

Comment: For example: I have the same problem with search within Title. The query  [Publication Title: "recommendations"] AND [Publication Title: "machine learning"] returns a paper with title "Recommendations as treatments: debiasing learning and evaluation"...

Comment: same issue. still not solved.. makes it basically impossible to do systematic reviews on ACM library